# CyclicalReferenceException while using Betwixt

Tags: java, reference, cyclic-reference, betwixt

I have cyclical references in my hibernate domain model which is causing Betwixt to fail.  I don't want to change my domain model.

How do I change Betwixt to ignore the cyclical reference?